# How do I change the status in a field when a button is clicked using a script

Tags: html, jquery, model-view-controller

When a person clicks the addressed link on a status report that is marked "ContainsErrors" I would like it to change the status to "Accepted". It is my first time writing a script, can someone help me with that? The below script does nothing.

Where they would click to change the status:

```
<a id="addressed" asp-route-id="@item.BatchHeaderId" style="text-decoration:underline">Addressed</a>
```

This is the script so far:

```
    <script>
$('#addressed').click(function(){
     if($(this).data('BatchProcessStatusCode')=="ContainErrors"){
        $("#BatchProcessStatusCode").val("Accepted");

});
```

});

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

***Updated***

```
<div class="row box-shadow--6dp" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; border:solid; border-width:1px; padding-top:10px;">
    <form asp-controller="Batch" asp-action="Explorer" method="get">
        <table class="spaced-table">
            <tr>
                @if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("FacilityIdentifier") != "")
                {
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="FacilityIdentifier" type="hidden" value="@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("FacilityIdentifier")" readonly />
                    </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td><label>Facility Name:</label></td>
                    <td><select asp-for="FacilityIdentifier" asp-items="@ViewBag.FacilityIdentifier" style="height:22px;width:300px;"><option></option></select></td>
                }
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Batch Status:</label></td>
                <td><select asp-for="BatchProcessStatusCode" asp-items="@ViewBag.BatchProcessStatusCode" style="height:22px;width:300px;"><option></option></select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>From Date:</label></td>
                <td><input asp-for="FromDate" type="date" style="height:22px;width:300px;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>To Date:</label></td>
                <td><input asp-for="ToDate" type="date" style="height:22px;width:300px;" /><br /><span asp-validation-for="ToDate" style="font-size:0.9em;color:red;"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="float:right; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <button id="BatchExplorerSearch" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>&nbsp;
            <a asp-action="Explorer" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Clear</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="box-shadow--6dp table-container-search">
    <div class="row" style="font-weight:bold; margin-right:0px;">
        <div class="col-9">
            Batch Explorer Results:
            @if (Model.BatchHeader.Count() == 0)
            {
                <div class="alert alert-info">No records found!</div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            @if (Model.BatchHeader.Count() > 1 && Model.BatchHeader.Count() != 0)
            {
                <span>@Model.BatchHeader.Count() Batches Found</span>
            }
            else
            {
                <span>@Model.BatchHeader.Count() Batch Found</span>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrolling-region">
        @foreach (var item in Model.BatchHeader)
        {
            @if (item.BatchProcessStatusCode == "Accepted")
            {
                <table class="table-sm table-borderless box-shadow--6dp condensed-table table-card table-3col" style="background-color: cornsilk;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Facility.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FacilityIdentifier == item.FacilityIdentifier).FacilityName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="Summary" asp-route-id="@item.BatchHeaderId" style="text-decoration:underline">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.BatchIdentifier)
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Services Reported: @item.PgnetEncounterBatchDetails.Count()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Submission Date: @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CreateDate)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Status: @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.BatchProcessStatusCodeNavigation.BatchProcessStatusLabel)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Errors Found: @item.BatchErrorDetails.Count()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="FileDetails" asp-route-id="@item.BatchHeaderId" style="text-decoration:underline">Source File</a>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
            else if (item.BatchProcessStatusCode == "ContainsErrors")
            {
                <table class="table-sm table-borderless box-shadow--6dp condensed-table table-card table-3col" style="background-color: salmon;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Facility.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FacilityIdentifier == item.FacilityIdentifier).FacilityName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="Summary" asp-route-id="@item.BatchHeaderId" style="text-decoration:underline">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.BatchIdentifier)
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Services Reported: @item.PgnetEncounterBatchDetails.Count()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Submission Date: @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CreateDate)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Status: @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.BatchProcessStatusCodeNavigation.BatchProcessStatusLabel)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Errors Found: @item.BatchErrorDetails.Count()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="FileDetails" asp-route-id="@item.BatchHeaderId" style="text-decoration:underline">Source File</a> |
                                <a  asp-action="Explorer" asp-route-id="@item.BatchHeaderId" name="addressed" style="text-decoration:underline">Addressed</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
            else if (item.BatchProcessStatusCode == "Withdrawn")
            {
                <table class="table-sm table-borderless box-shadow--6dp condensed-table table-card table-3col" style="background-color: gray;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Facility.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FacilityIdentifier == item.FacilityIdentifier).FacilityName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="Summary" asp-route-id="@item.BatchHeaderId" style="text-decoration:underline">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.BatchIdentifier)
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Services Reported: @item.PgnetEncounterBatchDetails.Count()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Submission Date: @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CreateDate)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Status: @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.BatchProcessStatusCodeNavigation.BatchProcessStatusLabel)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Errors Found: @item.BatchErrorDetails.Count()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="FileDetails" asp-route-id="@item.BatchHeaderId" style="text-decoration:underline">Source File</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
            else
            {
                <table class="table-sm table-borderless box-shadow--6dp condensed-table table-card table-3col">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Facility.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FacilityIdentifier == item.FacilityIdentifier).FacilityName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="Summary" asp-route-id="@item.BatchHeaderId" style="text-decoration:underline">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.BatchIdentifier)
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Services Reported: @item.PgnetEncounterBatchDetails.Count()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Submission Date: @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CreateDate)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Status: @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.BatchProcessStatusCodeNavigation.BatchProcessStatusLabel)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Errors Found: @item.BatchErrorDetails.Count()
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a asp-action="FileDetails" asp-route-id="@item.BatchHeaderId" style="text-decoration:underline">Source File</a> |
                                Addressed
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you may need to understand what jQuery `.data` does: [jQuery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Could you provide us with the whole HTML code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.